# Getting null for id when Id set for Junit tests

Tags: java, junit, null, junit5

I am writing Junit tests for a program that involves a database people can change or update. When trying to test the option to get a record with the ID the ID keeps coming back null even when I tried to manually set it in the Junit test. I took the manually set ID out because realistically its an auto-incremental id and the ID should be taken care of.

This is my Junit test as a whole:

```
private BloodDonationLogic bDLogic;
private BloodBankLogic bBLogic;
private BloodDonation expectedEntity;
private BloodBank bb;
/**
 * Sets up tomCat before testing begins
 * @throws Exception 
 */

@BeforeAll
final static void setUpBeforeClass() throws Exception{
    TomcatStartUp.createTomcat("/SimpleBloodBank-1", "common.ServletListener", "simplebloodbank-PU-test");
    
   
}

/**
 * Tears down tomcat after testing
 * @throws Exception 
 */

@AfterAll
final static void tearDownAfterClass() throws Exception{
    TomcatStartUp.stopAndDestroyTomcat();
}

/**
 * Sets up 
 * @throws ParseException 
 */

   @BeforeEach
    final void setUp() throws ParseException{
    bDLogic = LogicFactory.getFor("BloodDonation");
    bBLogic = LogicFactory.getFor("BloodBank");
EntityManager em = EMFactory.getEMF().createEntityManager();

em.getTransaction().begin();

SimpleDateFormat format2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd");
String strEstablished = "2021-08-08";
Date established = format2.parse(strEstablished);

BloodBank bloodBank = new BloodBank();
    //if result is null create the entity and persist it

       
     
       bloodBank.setName( "JUNIT2" );
       bloodBank.setPrivatelyOwned( true );
       bloodBank.setEstablished(established);
       bloodBank.setEmplyeeCount( 111 );
        //persist the dependency first
        bb = em.merge( bloodBank );
    

BloodDonation entity = new BloodDonation();
String strCreated = "2021-08-08";
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd");
Date created = format.parse(strCreated);



entity.setBloodBank(bb);
entity.setBloodGroup(BloodGroup.B);
entity.setRhd(RhesusFactor.Positive);
entity.setMilliliters(2000);
entity.setCreated(created);

expectedEntity = em.merge(entity);
em.getTransaction().commit();
em.close();

  }
/**
 * Deletes both the expected BloodDonation entity and the created BloodBank from the system 
 * @throws Exception 
 */

@AfterEach
 final void tearDown() throws Exception{
    if(expectedEntity != null){
     bDLogic.delete(expectedEntity);
  }
   if(bb != null){
      bBLogic.delete(bb);
 }
}
/**
 * Tests getting all the values in the BloodDonationLogic
 */
   @Test     
    public void testGetAll() {
    List<BloodDonation> list = bDLogic.getAll();
    int originalSize = list.size();
    
    assertNotNull (expectedEntity);
    bDLogic.delete(expectedEntity);
    
    list = bDLogic.getAll();
    assertEquals(originalSize -1, list.size());

}
 
/**
 * Asserting that the expected values and the actual values in the test are equal
 * @param expected
 * @param actual 
 */

public void assertBloodDonationEquals(BloodDonation expected, BloodDonation actual){
    assertEquals(expected.getId(), actual.getId());
    assertEquals(expected.getBloodBank(), actual.getBloodBank());
    assertEquals(expected.getBloodGroup(), actual.getBloodGroup());
    assertEquals(expected.getCreated(), actual.getCreated());
    assertEquals(expected.getMilliliters(), actual.getMilliliters());
    assertEquals(expected.getRhd(), actual.getRhd());
    
}


/**
 * testing the ability to get a BloodDonation record with BloodBank ID
 */


@Test
public void testGetBloodDonationWithBloodBank(){
    int foundFull = 0;
    List<BloodDonation> returnedDonations;
    returnedDonations = bDLogic.getBloodDonationsWithBloodBank(expectedEntity.getId());
    for(BloodDonation bloodDonation: returnedDonations){
        assertEquals(expectedEntity.getId(), bloodDonation.getId());
        if(bloodDonation.getId().equals(expectedEntity.getId())){
            assertEquals(expectedEntity, bloodDonation);
            foundFull++;
        
      }
    }
    assertEquals(0, foundFull);
            }

/**
 * Testing the ability to get a BloodDonation record with BloodGroup
 */
@Test
public void testGetBloodDonationWithBloodGroup(){
    int foundFull = 0;
    List<BloodDonation> returnedDonations = bDLogic.getBloodDonationWithBloodGroup(expectedEntity.getBloodGroup());
    for(BloodDonation bloodDonation: returnedDonations){
        assertEquals(expectedEntity.getBloodGroup(), bloodDonation.getBloodGroup());
        if(bloodDonation.getId().equals(expectedEntity.getId())){
            assertBloodDonationEquals(expectedEntity, bloodDonation);
            foundFull++;
            
        }
    }
    assertEquals(0, foundFull);
}

/**
 * Testing the ability to get a BloodDonation record with the milliletres entered
 */
@Test
public void testGetBloodDonationWithMillileters(){
    int foundFull = 0;
    List<BloodDonation> returnedDonations = bDLogic.getBloodDonationWithMilliliters(expectedEntity.getMilliliters());
    for(BloodDonation bloodDonation: returnedDonations){
        assertEquals(expectedEntity.getMilliliters(), bloodDonation.getMilliliters());
        if(bloodDonation.getId().equals(expectedEntity.getId())){
            assertBloodDonationEquals(expectedEntity, bloodDonation);
            foundFull++;
        }
    }
    assertEquals(0, foundFull);
    
}
/**
 * Testing the ability to get a blood donation record with the rhesus factor entered
 */
@Test
public void testGetBloodDonationWithRhesusFactor(){
    int foundFull = 0;
    List<BloodDonation> returnedDonations = bDLogic.getBloodDonationsWithRhd(expectedEntity.getRhd());
    for(BloodDonation bloodDonation: returnedDonations){
        assertEquals(expectedEntity.getRhd(), bloodDonation.getRhd());
        if(bloodDonation.getId().equals(expectedEntity.getId())){
            assertEquals(expectedEntity, bloodDonation);
            foundFull++;
        }
    }
    assertEquals(1, foundFull);
}

@Test
public void testCreateEntity(){
    Map<String, String[]> testMap =  new HashMap<>();
    testMap.put(BloodDonationLogic.ID, new String [] {Integer.toString(expectedEntity.getId())});
    testMap.put(BloodDonationLogic.BANK_ID, new String [] {Integer.toString(expectedEntity.getBloodBank().getId())});
    testMap.put(BloodDonationLogic.BLOOD_GROUP, new String[] {expectedEntity.getBloodGroup().toString()});
    testMap.put(BloodDonationLogic.MILLILITERS, new String[]{Integer.toString(expectedEntity.getMilliliters())});
    testMap.put(BloodDonationLogic.RHESUS_FACTOR, new String [] {expectedEntity.getRhd().getSymbol()});
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd");
    String strCreated = format.format(expectedEntity.getCreated());
    testMap.put(BloodDonationLogic.CREATED, new String[]{strCreated});
    
    BloodDonation returnedDonation = bDLogic.createEntity(testMap);
    assertEquals(expectedEntity, returnedDonation);
    

}

@Test
public void testGetColumnNames(){
    List<String> list = bDLogic.getColumnNames();
    assertEquals(Arrays.asList("Donation ID", "Bank ID", "Milliliters", "Blood Group", "RHD", "Created"), list);
    
}

@Test
public void testColumnCodes(){
    List<String> list = bDLogic.getColumnCodes();
    assertEquals(Arrays.asList(ID, BANK_ID, MILLILITERS, BLOOD_GROUP, RHESUS_FACTOR, CREATED),list);
}

@Test
public void testExtractDataAsAList(){
   List<?> list = bDLogic.extractDataAsList(expectedEntity);
   assertEquals(expectedEntity.getId(), list.get(0));
   assertEquals(expectedEntity.getBloodBank(), list.get(1));
   assertEquals(expectedEntity.getMilliliters(), list.get(2));
   assertEquals(expectedEntity.getBloodGroup(), list.get(3));
   assertEquals(expectedEntity.getRhd(), list.get(4));
   assertEquals(expectedEntity.getCreated(), list.get(5));
   
}
 @Test
final void testGetWithId() {
    //using the id of test blood bank get another blood bank from logic
    BloodDonation returnedDonation = bDLogic.getWithId( expectedEntity.getId() );

    //the two blood banks must be the same
    assertEquals( expectedEntity, returnedDonation ); //this returned null. It says it expected id=11 but it comes back null instead
}
```

Comment: Put a breakpoint in `getWithId` and see what's happening.

Comment: I tried that, the only thing it would give me was the same error message expected: donationId = 11 but was <null>